Why am I getting a Error(13) Permission Denied with credential but not using username?
I have the following working...
sudo mount.cifs //10.3.1.9/Users/me/Shared /mnt/bigboy -o user=me@gmail.com,password=...
Now I want to use fstab and I want to use a cred file. I try the following
sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/etc/samba/creds //10.0.0.9/Users/me/Shared /mnt/bigboy
With the creds file as
username=me@gmail.com
password=...

When I try that I get
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

